# Spark .csv viariable number of columns

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have a case class like that:

```
case class ResultDays (name: String, number: Double, values: Double*)
```

and I want to save it into a `.csv` file

```
resultRDD.toDF()
  .coalesce(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("res/output/result.csv")
```

Unfortunately I have this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support array<double> data type.
```

So, how can I insert a variable number of `values` and save it into a `.csv`?

Comment: CSV, as a _format_, does not support a variable number of values, in the sense that all records must have the same columns. Do you know anything about the number of values expected? Perhaps the _maximum_ number of values the `values` member might have?

Comment: I've to write the same number of `values` for every row, but I don't know how many `values` I have before run.

Comment: OK - but once you have `resultRDD`, you can assume all records have the same number of values?

Comment: Yes, but using `ResultDays` class it contains `Double*` and it seems I cannot use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume all records in `resultRDD` have the same number of columns  in `values` - you can read the `first()` record, use it to determine the number of values in the arrays, and convert these arrays into separate columns:

```
// determine number of "extra" columns:
val extraCols = resultRDD.first().values.size

// create a sequence of desired columns:
val columns = Seq($"name", $"number") ++ (1 to extraCols).map(i => $"values"(i - 1) as s"col$i")

// select the above columns before saving:
resultRDD.toDF()
  .select(columns: _*)
  .coalesce(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("res/output/result.csv")
```

Example CSV result would be something like:

```
name,number,col1,col2
a,0.1,0.01,0.001
b,0.2,0.02,0.002
c,0.3,0.03,0.003
```